# linq select a new, by list of columns names

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a dataTable that I get from DB, 
And I want to retrieve the data by linq

my dataTable From DB

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|    column_1     |    column_2     |    column_3     |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| data_column_1_1 | data_column_2_1 | data_column_3_1 |
| data_column_1_2 | data_column_2_2 | data_column_3_2 |
| data_column_1_3 | data_column_2_3 | data_column_3_3 |
| data_column_1_4 | data_column_2_4 | data_column_3_4 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I do not know the number of columns in the table 
but did I get another table with the names of all columns

the column's names

```
+----------------+
| column's names |
+----------------+
| column_1       |
| column_2       |
| column_3       |
+----------------+
```

How do I do this? 
I want it to look like this

```
  var list = DataTableFromDB.AsEnumerable (). Select (x => new 
{
  row1 = x.Field <string> ("row1"), 
  row2 = x.Field <string> ("row2"), 
});
```

But dynamically,
can help me?

Comment: try [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28VS.100%29.aspx) and Add() method(with cast to [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630214%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) to add dynamic property to Expanded Object.

Code:

```
var list = DataTableFromDB.AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
            {
                var sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();
                foreach (var col in columnsNames)
                {
                    ((IDictionary<String, Object>)sampleObject)
                     .Add(col, x.Field<string>(col));
                }
                return sampleObject;
            });
```

Comment: I want to get it like data members
Not like dictinary(key,value)

Comment: @lealam, If you declare sampleObject as dynamic, you can access member dynamically. So what you want do it?